# I have a single div and it needs to be duplicated dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, display

I have a single div and a unknown number(say n) of rows of data. i need to show that data on my html cards
and these cards are to be generated dynamically by the output value(n).

say if i have 10 rows of data.my div element needs to be created 10 times and each row data is to be displayed on each div

by the way i am using PHP for backend.

here is my codes
This is my div

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <h1><?php echo"$value"; ?></h1>
      <h3><?php<?php echo"$description";?></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my php code

```
<?php
      $conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","","programmingpioneers");
          if(!$conn)
          {
            echo "connection_failed";
          }
          else{
            //echo "sucess";
          }
          $query= "select title,description from problems where difficulty='hard'";
          $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
          $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
          if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) 
          {
              echo "sucess<br>";
              while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                       $title=$row[0];
                   $description=$row[1];
                   echo "$title <br> $description";
                }


           }

  else {
        echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
         ?>
```

if i try to but my div inside

```
echo"$title <br>$description";
```

it is throwing the following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'row' (T_STRING), expecting ';' or ',' in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\useless.php on line 19
```

Comment: You're already almost there. You see that `echo "$title <br> $description";`? All you have to do is put your html div code in there in a similar way: `echo "<div class=...` etc :) Btw, please don't use tags that have nothing to do with your question. Javascript for example.

Comment: @icecub i already tried it but no use "it is showing my html code as output"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use loop in the div you want to have again and again.Please check the code if it works for you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwnnE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwnnE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Without having all your data available I'm unable to test it, but this should be the correct way of doing it. I left comments in the code and removed a bunch of syntax errors that you made:

```
<?php

// Create MySQLi object
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","programmingpioneers");

// Verify MySQL connection
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
}

// Query
$query = "SELECT title,description FROM problems WHERE difficulty = 'hard'";

// Run query
if($result = $conn->query($query)) {

    // Loop through query results
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "<div class='column'>";
        echo "<div class='card'>";
        echo "<h1>". $row['title'] ."</h1>";
        echo "<h3>". $row['description'] ."</h3>";
        echo "</div></div></div>";
    }

// Output query errors
} else {
    echo "Failed to select title, description: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}

// Close the MySQLi connection
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: i am now fine with solution provided by another contributor ,but now the problem with adjustment of the divs i want to put them in order

Comment: @maneeshsandra Just change your query to: `difficulty = 'hard' ORDER BY id DESC` (or ASC if you want it the other way around). Assuming `id` is the unique key of your database table here, but you can use any column that can be sorted instead.

Comment: i am completely fine with php and backend now. only problem with css

Comment: @maneeshsandra You're going to have to create a new question for that. I don't know any of your CSS code (its not in your question) and it's not advised to create multiple distinct questions in a single post